# Apt is not finding package that is supposed to be there

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I had installed bitmask with the wrong repository (just used their vivid with wily and it worked fine). Now I wanted to switch over their now available wily repo and followed [their instructions](https://bitmask.net/en/install/linux#ubuntu-1510-wily-werewolf) how to remove the key. Add new key and stuff.

```
> $ sudo apt-get install bitmask                                                                                                                 
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paket bitmask ist nicht verfügbar, wird aber von einem anderen Paket
referenziert. Das kann heißen, dass das Paket fehlt, dass es abgelöst
wurde oder nur aus einer anderen Quelle verfügbar ist.

E: Für Paket »bitmask« existiert kein Installationskandidat.
```

But now it says there is no bitmask package but tells me that there are other packages that referece it. So what should I do now. I tryed apt-get clean and a few other things with no luck.

I tryed to purge bitmask and leap-keyring ...

First I thought there are old packets still cached and that is why

```
sudo apt-cache policy leap-keyring                                                                                                           
leap-keyring:
  Installiert:           (keine)
  Installationskandidat: 2015.02.26+0~20150512161821.18+vivid~1.gbp30002f
  Versionstabelle:
     2015.02.26+0~20150512161821.18+vivid~1.gbp30002f 0
        500 http://deb.bitmask.net/debian/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

Gives me the vivid version but then I checked [their pools](http://deb.bitmask.net/debian/pool/main/b/bitmask/) and it seems they not having packages for wily in there. Maybe on purpose because the vivid packages still work. I don't know.

Maybe this has something to do with me removing the key and trying to update without the key, I only now realize that the key is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The package `bitmask` is in the Universe repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitmask
```

---

The correct repository definition for `leap-keyring` and **your** `bitmask` version is

```
deb http://deb.leap.se/debian testing main
deb-src http://deb.leap.se/debian testing main
```

and the necessary key

```
gpg --armor --export 0x1E34A1828E207901  | sudo apt-key add -
```

And you are right - there are no Wily packages.

Debian is a little bit different compared with Ubuntu regarding the naming of repositories.